# How prevent react unmounting without react-router (Prompt)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

Hello I'm facing a challenge with REACT. Is possible to stop a component from unmounting WITHOUT react-router-dom (Promp)?

I couldn't think of anything useful or find any resource except react-router-dom Prompt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not enough context on understanding your problem